# File upload referencing record that is not inserted yet

Tags: java, spring, web, upload

i have a question that i couldn't find a satisfying answer.

i have a "Add Product" screen, this product has zero or many images. In this same screen there is the upload option.

My question is: how can i upload pictures to the product, if i don't have it`s id yet? since it is not saved on database yet.

Is there any best practice for this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm just listing down my points on how to handle it:

1. **Handle both at once** - Send the Picture and Details of the product at once on save/add button click using `enctype=”multipart/form-data”` (Using [spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html))

   - Now you can handle in your code. Perform validations.
   - If it passes all validations, then upload the image/save the image.
   - Send the url/filepath to the Object/DB where product is getting saved.
   - **Drawback:**

     - Say user has already uploaded the files and is filling the product details. In which case, We're still waiting for user to enter all the details of the Product and then upload.
     - The final upload during save is going to take time. (Second option can overcome this)
2. **Upload Images First as in when they're available and then Product on save** -

   - Upload the Image first to the server (As in when user adds an image, keep uploading).
   - Let Server save all these images at a temp-place and return a UUID number to uniquely identify these images.
   - On save/add action, let client send all those UUID's list that it got from server during upload time. Now server can identify what all images can be moved from temp directory back to central server or associate the images with Product.
   - You can have another `Cron Job` or `SessionTimeoutListener` or A call from client when user backs out of Product Page without save or **A combination of all 3** to remove those images which are not associated with any product for say last *X minutes* (Session timeout minutes)
   - **Drawback:**

     - Needs a lot of changes and post-processing/clean-up overhead.
3. **Handle Product first then Image** -

   - Push product details first to server on save and server return the productId that got saved.
   - Now client makes another call to server with productId and Images.
   - **Drawback :**

     - We're relying on client to handle transactions, which is bad.
     - Inconsistency with data might grow.
     - The time taken for the entire process might grow compared to other 2 approaches.

*PS : I feel the second opinion to be good. This is just my opinion.*